# CSS margins for elements with no width

Tags: html, css, centering

I need to center a div element that has no width (it takes its width from the inner div.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .outer {
        padding: 10px;
        /*margin: auto; (doesn´t work)*/
        background-color: #000;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .inner {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #CCC;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas how to fix this without setting a width?

Comment: `body { text-align: center }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can this on the body or .outer

This will center align your div horizontally and vertically.

```
position: absolute; 
top:50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

For horizontal centering , given that parent is relative;

```
   .outer {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #000;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```